# Backbone.js getting data on POST request

Tags: rest, backbone.js, jax-rs

I am new to backbone.js.I am trying to POST data with my service and it returns me data. My service is: `http://192.168.1.3:8080/app/search/candidate` It takes Input as

```
{
  "skills":["c","java"]
 }
```

And it returns list of users to me. so I created collection in backbone and tried 
My code is

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var EntityList = Backbone.Collection.extend({       
        model: UserModel,
        url: `'http://192.168.1.3:8080/app/search/candidate'`

        });



 var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : '#mydiv',
    template : _.template($("#details").html()),
    initialize : function() {   
          var self = this;     
          this.coll = new EntityList();
         // this.coll.bind("reset", _.bind(this.render, this));
         this.coll.fetch({
         data:JSON.stringify({'skills':['c','java']}),

         type: 'POST' ,   

         success: function(){
                 //console.log(this.coll.toJSON());
                 self.render();
                 }}); 
        } ,          

    render : function() {
      // the persons will be "visible" in your template
      this.$el.html(this.template({ persons: this.coll.toJSON() }));
      return this;
    }

            });
var view = new View();
```

But it gives me  Status Code:   HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Where I am missing?
Header for request from chrom debugger is

```
   Request URL:http://192.168.1.3:8080/app/search/candidate
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:JSESSIONID=763119F314E1485DCC8B838F4539BA78
Host:192.168.1.3:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/jobSearch.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/31.0.1650.63 Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 17 Feb 2014 11:46:00 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: I find a few pieces odd there :) Is your URL supposed to be like that, with the extra \`'s? Also, I don't believe you need to `JSON.stringify` your POST data. Have you tried making that request via `http://192.168.1.3:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`? Chrome can be picky with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked, see the request headers in the console is this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CRkG/) :

```
    this.coll.fetch({

        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        },

        data: JSON.stringify({'skills':['c','java']}),

        type: 'POST',

        success: function () {
            //console.log(this.coll.toJSON());
            self.render();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Can you set a jsfiddle ? Have you set the `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` in your application ? Try to check its value before you call fetch `console.log(Backbone.emulateJSON)`

Comment: If you set the `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` you will get the error, because the Content-type will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: So you have to set `Backbone.emulateJSON = false;`

Comment: now It gives error : POST http://192.168.1.3:8080/app/search/candidate 415 (Unsupported Media Type) jquery.min.js:

Comment: Header for request from chrome debugger ? And what version of Backbone you are using ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47657/discussion-between-prashant-thorat-and-rida-benhammane)

Comment: I updated my quetion with latest header and i am using Backbone 0.9.2 and 1.3.3 underscore from cdnjs

Comment: Have you tested the last jsfiddle ? here's what I get : RequestHeaders
Content-Type application/json
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Answer (score 1):

By default, Backbone requests media type "application/json", and it looks like your server can't handle that. To work around that, look into `emaulateJSON` http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON

Comment: My server is handeling data as application/json.I tested it using postman tool. and working fine

Comment: Yes I am sure I tested it using Content-Type:application/json with row data {
  "skills":["c","java"] 
} and it works fine