# stringify part of an object for server request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm overriding the fetch method of a Backbone Collection to send a request to a different url in certain circumstances, and I have to send some data with it. The new fetch method (copied from another SO answer) looks like this

```
fetch(options){

    if(options && options.data){
         options = _.extend({url : '/someendpoint/'}, options || {});
     }

    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

When I call the fetch method in a view, I pass it some data (that comes in with the options parameter in fetch)

```
 callFetchMethod(){

   var min = $("#min").val();
   var max = $("#max").val();
   var range = {};
   range['min'] = min;
   range['max'] = max;
   mycollection.fetch({'data': range}); //send the object with min and max to collection
  }
```

The problem is that the data object is not being recognized on the server. I've tried calling `JSON.stringify(range)` before sending it to the Collection and also `JSON.stringify(options.data)` inside the collection, but all to no avail.

I need to use a new url and I need to send data to the server. How can I do it in the fetch method above?

**Update:** this is what happens in various attempts to stringify the whole options object or just options.data

If I stringify the whole options object like this

if (options && options.data){
        options = _.extend({url: '/someendpoint'}, options || {});
        options.data = JSON.stringify(options);
        console.log(options, "options in collection");
    }

no data gets sent to the server (and the right url isn’t called)

```
{"url":"/someendpoint","data":"{\"min\":\"1429740602093\",\"max\":\"1429740602093\"}"}
```

if I stringify options.data like this

```
if (options && options.data){
            options = _.extend({url: '/someendpoint'}, options || {});
            options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
            console.log(options, "options in collection");
        }
```

this is out output in the console

```
Object {url: "/someendpoint", data: "{"min":"1429740602093","max":"1429740602093"}"} "options in collection"
```

and I get an error on the server that says

```
the server throws an unexpected end of JSON input error
```

Comment: What about just the options? `JSON.stringify(options)`

Comment: @colemc I updated the OP with details about what happens when I stringify options.data and also the whole options object `JSON.stringify(options)`

Comment: is there a way to keep the url and data options distinct using `apply` rather than `call`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `Backbone.Collection.fetch` is calling `Collection.sync('read', this, options)`, where `'read'` is the HTTP request method. According to the [Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) this translates to an `HTTP GET`. And [we know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299780/2112866) that according to spec a `GET` request should ignore all data payloads.

So..., we'll either have to append the `range` data to the url, or use a `POST` request instead.

## Set your url parameters for fetch

Setting the collection url dynamically is straight forward. In your example, you can do,

```
callFetchMethod(){
   // assume mycollection already instantiatied
   var min = $("#min").val();
   var max = $("#max").val();
   mycollection.url = '/someendpoint?max=' + max '&min=' + min;
   mycollection.fetch(); // The url is already set
}
```

## Using POST to fetch

Based on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21826036/2112866), we can override the `POST` request on fetch by providing a `type` property. So, our new `callFetchMethod` would look like:

```
callFetchMethod(){
   // assume mycollection already instantiatied
   var min = $("#min").val();
   var max = $("#max").val();
   var range = {};
   range['min'] = min;
   range['max'] = max;
   mycollection.fetch({type: 'POST', data: JSON.stringify(range)});
}
```

and this should work because what Backbone is doing is:

```
var xhr = options.xhr = Backbone.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
```

and while, `params` has a `type` property set to `GET` by `Collection.fetch()`, `_.extend()` overwrites that prop with the `type` property from `options`, as well as provides the `data` property to the `Backbone.ajax()` (which, by the way is nothing but a thin wrapper for `$.ajax`).

**Note:**

> This code is untested, please let me know if you run into any issues